# PDOStatement execute doesn't fill values with Mysql-ODBC

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, odbc

I'm trying code below to insert a data to my Mysql Table

```
$pdo = new PDO('odbc:MYSQL', 'user', 'pass');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdo->query('use mydb');

$query=$pdo->query("CREATE TABLE MEMBERS (ID INT PRIMARY KEY, NAME NVARCHAR(20), DESCRIPTION NVARCHAR(20))");

try {
$query=$pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO MEMBERS (ID, NAME,DESCRIPTION) VALUES(?,?,?)',array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
$query->execute(array(9,'JOHN DOE', 'IT'));
}catch (\Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}
```

Then I'm getting this error:

```
[MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.5.43-0ubuntu0.14.04.1-log]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' , )' at line 1 (SQLExecute[1064] at /build/php5-RpYHCf/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/ext/pdo_odbc/odbc_stmt.c:254)'
```

And I can see the query in the Mysql Log file :

```
INSERT INTO MEMBERS (ID, NAME,DESCRIPTION) VALUES(, , )
```

So, execute function is unable to populate values from array.

Note: I have tried VALUES(:ID,:NAME,:DESCRIPTION) didn' worked.
Also, I have tried execute after bindParam(), this didn't worked too.

Am I doing some thing wrong?

Comment: What is `GOREV`? Not seeing that in provided code.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have forget to translate that field. Please check the new edited version of this post.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I doing some thing wrong?

Yes.

For some reason you are using ODBC to connect mysql database, which makes you one of very few people who ever tried such an unusual coupling of technologies.

Let me suggest you to use [standard mysql driver](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php). I am sure there will be not a slightest problem with the very same queries

Comment: Yes, I know it is not a good way to connect mysql with ODBC and over PDO. But I should use this way on my project.